# SharePoint 2013 - GroupUserAdded event receiver not firing when adding user programmatically to group

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, spgroup

I've added a *GroupUserAdded* event receiver to a SPWeb and confirmed the correct deployment via SharePoint Manager.

Additionally, the call to the receiver class is working fine when adding a user via SP Site Settings page *People and Groups*.

The caveat I'm experiencing right now - and couldn't find a fix for - is that programmatically adding a user to a group as follows won't trigger the event receiver. Any idea as though why this behaviour occurs would be appreciated.

```
var firstGroup = web.SiteGroups[0];
var adminUser = web.EnsureUser("administrator");
firstGroup.AddUser(adminUser);
firstGroup.Update();
```

ty,
Frank

Comment: The question can be closed. The event was fired correctly but the debugger was not attached to the correct process.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); after the Update. Sometimes async events are not triggering properly.

Similar case but with item event receiver:
[Programmatically changing a field won't trigger the event receiver](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147512/programmatically-changing-a-field-wont-trigger-the-event-receiver/147517)